# wordpress advanced custom fields background image

Tags: php, css, wordpress, background-image, custom-fields

I am trying to set an image uploaded through custom fields plugin and have it display as the background of a div (which is used in a slider).

However the image is not displaying...I have text in the custom fields and that is showing okay so I think its something to do with the line of code I am using to pull in the image.

I am trying to set the background of .slide1 with the image.

The custom field name is slide1_background.

HTML:

```
<div class="slide1" style="background-image:url('<?php the_field('slide_bg1'); ?>');">
<div class="slide1-cont"><p class="slide-text">
<h1><?php the_field('slide_title1'); ?></h1>
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/images/line.png" /></p>
<p><?php the_field('slide_content1'); ?></p></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slide1{
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
background-position:center;
height: 800px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the difference in your code in your question, where you try to set the background-image, compared to the code in your comment in another answer where you're setting it as an image source.

`the_field('slide_bg1')` returns an array, so you're trying to set the background image source as a PHP array which gets converted to a string as "Array" so in your HTML it'll look like: `background-image:url('Array')`

You need to get the field first, then echo the `url` element of the returned array as the source of the background image:

```
$image = get_field( 'slide_bg1' );
if ( !empty( $image ) ) { ?>
    <div class="slide1" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $image['url']; ?>');">
<?php }
```

Comment: Got it working by wrapping the div in the code you supplied. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I get text at the top that appears to be the image name...i think it may be an error? http://imgur.com/7wU6W7u

57, , 2f91dc29201043.55e72a3cc8810, , , image/jpeg, http://localhost:1337/kite/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/2f91dc29201043.55e72a3cc8810.jpg, 1200, 1200, Array');

Comment: That seems like something else is echoing out each element of the array. The code I posted above only echoes the `url` element which is what's required to set the background image

Answer (score -1):

Use `echo`

`<div class="slide1" style="background-image:url('<?php echo the_field('slide_bg1'); ?>');">`

Comment: still no luck. When I inspect element it sees there is an image there but it does not display. When i open the image link in a new tab instead of opening the image it opens the homepage again...

Comment: Prepare it on the browser so that the image is visible then try to clone that in the code above.

Comment: when i use this code i can display the images, but when I wrap the div in this code and move the image into the style of where i want it, it doesn't display

<?php 
    $image = get_field('slide_bg1');
    if( !empty($image) ): ?>
    <img class="service-image" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>